# Temperature conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with these conditions.
I would like the body changes color depending on the temperature.
It works well but it is only the last color that is considered `'#e74c3c'` .
For example it is 15 degrees and I get the red `'#e74c3c`' then it does not 30 °.

```
if(weather.temp > 0) {
$('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#3498db'}, 1500);
} else {
$('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#3498db'}, 1500);
}

if(weather.temp > 10) {
$('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#f1c40f'}, 1500);
} else {
$('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#f1c40f'}, 1500);
 }  

if(weather.temp > 20) {
$('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#f39c12'}, 1500);
} else {
$('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#f39c12'}, 1500);
 }

if(weather.temp > 30) {
$('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#e74c3c'}, 1500);
} else {
$('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#e74c3c'}, 1500);
}
```

Comment: Because your final else will be triggered for anything <= 30. You should use one if, and several else ifs after it.

Comment: Look at the logic in your code. You have the same color in each clause  for every if statement. When it gets to the final if statement it sets the background color to #e74c3c no matter what.

Comment: What should happen if `weather.temp <= 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your final else will be triggered for anything <= 30. You should use one if, and several else ifs after it.

```
if (weather.temp <= 10) {
    $('body').animate({
        backgroundColor: '#3498db'
    }, 1500);
} else if (weather.temp > 10 && weather.temp <= 20) {
    $('body').animate({
        backgroundColor: '#f1c40f'
    }, 1500);
} else if (weather.temp > 20 && weather.temp <= 30) {
    $('body').animate({
        backgroundColor: '#f39c12'
    }, 1500);
} else if (weather.temp > 30) {
    $('body').animate({
        backgroundColor: '#e74c3c'
    }, 1500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When execution reaches this:

```
if(weather.temp > 30) {
$('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#e74c3c'}, 1500);
} else {
$('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#e74c3c'}, 1500);
}
```

it will set your background color to #e74c3c or........ #e74c3c.

Chaining these together using else will give you the intended result:

```
if (weather.temp <= 10) {
    $('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#3498db'}, 1500);
} else if (weather.temp > 10 && weather.temp <= 20) {
    $('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#f1c40f'}, 1500);
} else if (weather.temp > 20 && weather.temp <= 30) {
    $('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#f39c12'}, 1500);
} else if (weather.temp > 30) {
    $('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#e74c3c'}, 1500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(weather.temp >= 0 && weather.temp <= 10 ) {
    $('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#3498db'}, 1500);
} else if(weather.temp > 10 && weather.temp <= 20 ) {
    $('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#f1c40f'}, 1500);
} else if(weather.temp > 20 && weather.temp <= 30 ) {
    $('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#f39c12'}, 1500);
} else if(weather.temp > 30) {
    $('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#e74c3c'}, 1500);
}
```

You have to put a lower limit of `weather.temp >= 0` on your first if or else negative temperatures will trigger the color, which isn't part of the original specs. If you do want negative temperatures to trigger a color, then remove that clause.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it animates the color #f1c40f, but then goes through to the if statements for 20 degrees and 30 degrees and executes the else statements which animates the body regardless if it's 30+ degrees or not.

Try this:

```
if ( temp <= 10 )
   //animate body
else if( > 10 )
   //animate body
else if( > 20 )
   //animate body
else if( > 30 )
   //animate body
```